# Retrieve The Information From Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms

I have saved the information in the dictionary. and the dictionary in updated by the user. how can i retrieve the information from the dictionary. I have done the some code. put i do not know how to get the information from dictionary.

```
     //Create the dictionaries 
     Dictionary<int, int> waytosave = new Dictionary<int, int>();
     Dictionary<int ,int> numberControls = new Dictionary<int,int>();

          private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
       { 
    ///Setting up the coordinates
       int xCoor; 
       int yCoor;
       Random coor = new Random();
       int value =7; 
       for (int x = 0; x < value; x++)
          { 
        //Creating Random NumeircalUpdown. 
       //Using those the user can change the values.
        NumericUpDown numiNumber = new NumericUpDown();   
        xCoor = coor.Next(0, 500);     
       yCoor = coor.Next(0, 500);              
       numiNumber.Name = x.ToString();       
       numiNumber.Location = new Point(xCoor, yCoor);  
       numiNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 15);    
        numiNumber.Maximum = 100;    
        numiNumber.Minimum = 0; 
      //Saveing the numericalUpdowns   
        numberControls.Add(x, 0); 
       this.pnlNodes.Controls.Add(numiNumber); 

      //Make it respond to the clicking event    
         numiNumber.Click += new EventHandler(GetNumUpDownValue); 
         } 
         }
      //Get the values for the NumericUpDown
    public void GetNumUpDownValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { 
     int iname = int.Parse(((NumericUpDown)sender).Name);
     int ivalue = (int)((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;
    //check and update the list 
     if (waytosave.ContainsKey(iname))
       {
        waytosave[iname] = ivalue;
       }
           else
           { 
          waytosave.Add(iname, ivalue);
               } 

            txtOutputs.Text += "\r\r\n" + "   Node # " + iname + " = " + waytosave[iname].ToString(); 
             }

             private void btnRoundRobin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         {
              //how can i get the saved information from the waytosave dictionary
       //Can you advise me please????. 
         }
```

Comment: what information you need to retrieve?

Comment: the iname, and the ivalue?

Comment: I am thinking to have another 2 arrays that one for iname and one for ivalue.

Comment: To get value from the `Dictionary`, you may use the same indexer syntax as for the setting the value: `int data = waytosave[key];`

Comment: Maybe you should use a Tuple<int, int>, which seems to be semantically more suited to your needs. Else you can just loop through your Dictionary and get all values like `foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kv in waytosave)` kv.Key being iname, and kv.Value ivalue.

Comment: On a side note, you can replace the entire if-statement with a single line: txtOutputs.Text += "\r\r\n   Node # " + iname + " = " + (waytosave[iname] = ivalue);

Comment: that if statement to make my  dictionary  updated

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach, assuming you don't really care about the ordering of keys.

```
// Untested Code

int index = -1;
private void btnRoundRobin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var keys = waytosave.Keys;
    if(keys.Count == 0) return;
    index = (index + 1) % keys.Count;

    int key = keys[index];
    int value = waytosave[key];
}
```

Comment: it just giving me the name not the values.

Comment: actually  it just returning the index not the values in the dictionary.